# Android: Firebase results are showing twice in a row in different barcode scans

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-alertdialog

So my program is scanning an item using barcode and get(sucessfuly) its name from firebase and then im trying to print the name inside an alert dialog. My problem is that every time i scan an item the AlertDialog shows the preview scanned item. For example i scan item1. In the next product im going to scan it will print again item1's name.But In the next scan it will print the item2's name and so on .
The overal problem is that is printing the same name of one product in two different scans in a row. What is wrong?

In this code i return DataSnapshot value as a result of a method

```
public interface MyCallback {
        void onCallback(String value);
    }
    public void readData(final MyCallback myCallback) {
        final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items").child(myResult);
        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                name = dataSnapshot.child("itemname").getValue().toString();
                myCallback.onCallback(name);


            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(addquantityactivity.this,"there was an error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

and  this is the alert dialog builder

```
public void handleResult(Result result) {
         myResult = result.getText();

       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");

        readData(new MyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(String value) {
                //here i get the item's name from firebase 
                finalname=value;
            }
        });
      //and here im printing it to the builder
        builder.setMessage(finalname);
        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
        alert1.show();


    }
```

To mention i also have another firebase method in the same class which updates some data in the database. If this can give more information about the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show a dialog before the process is completed. You can try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Scan Result");

readData(new MyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCallback(String value) {
         finalname=value;
         builder.setMessage(finalname);
         AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
         alert1.show();
    }
});
```

You should show after completion

Comment: First of all thank you very much.. can you briefly explain your solution? just to understand

Comment: readData is an asynchronous process. You don't know when it will completed. Other lines keep to run while this process is running.